# Setting up a LAN Postfix server with fake domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, local-area-network

I want to set up a LAN in which several machines can send mail to each-other using a local Postfix server and a local DNS. The machines should be able to use fake domain names (guy@example.com, etc). Each machine should be identified by a separate domain. How should I configure Postfix and the DNS in order to do that?

Comment: You may want to check out [For fiction purposes, are there any reserved or non-existent top-level-domains writers can use in stories?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/68793/29) on [worldbuilding.se] for ideas on how to choose names guaranteed not to clash with names valid in the global DNS namespace.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal Email Routing**

Internal email works exactly like external email unless you want to get complicated.

- Create an internal domain for the LAN/WAN.  Whatever domain you choose to use internally will not work externally from your internal hosts unless you set up split views, but there is no need to go down that rabbit hole.
- Create MX records for that domain, pointing to a mail server that is reachable from your LAN/WAN.
- Configure the receiving server to allow connections from devices on your LAN/WAN and to recieve email for that domain.
- Configure the sending server and/or clients to allow sending to that domain.
- Avoid briding this network or mail server to the outside world.